# Jetpack Infinite Scroll not initialising on non-category pages

Tags: wordpress, infinite-scroll, jetpack

Recently we upgraded to Jetpack 4.8.2 and Infinite Scroll stopped working for all non-category pages. Previously it was working on the home page and on single pages. Previously I had the below code to hook in and activate support for IS on the other pages. It worked really nicely.

```
function tweakIF_support() {
    $supported = current_theme_supports( 'infinite-scroll') && is_home() || is_single() || is_category();
    return $supported;
}
add_filter( 'infinite_scroll_archive_supported', 'tweakIF_support' );
```

The problem now is it works for category pages but not the home page or single pages. The js isn't being added and the styles aren't going into the body which indicates to me that the init code isn't working anymore.

Any ideas what might have changed and what I have to change to get it going with single pages and the home page again.